# Resharper to create auto property when creating properties from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

If I have some XAML code that uses a `DataContext` Resharper picks up that there are issues when binding to properties that don't exist in that class and as part of the menu, you can select to "Create Property ".

[image: resharper 1]

Resharper then create a property in the class and asks for the property type to be specified.

[image: Resharper 2]

Once you provide the type, you can tab or press return and the member is created, however you are left with a `NotImplementedException` and it does not give the option to change the property to an auto property. Is it possible to make Resharper create at least an auto property when doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a new code snippet and then export it as a template. You can then import that template in Visual Studio as a Custom Template. Details on how to do it can be found [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html)

Hope it helps.